# How can I make mapbox 5.1.0 show >20 zoom level raster images?

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm making indoor-oriented application and I got stuck. Because mapbox limits zoom level to 20. I tried setting tileset and layer setMaxZoom(22), but It shows image no more than 20 level. I need only 21 and 22level images to show.
I can see more than 22 from mapbox 0.7 on web from same source. so it is not serverside problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to change the zoom level further than the set maximum level of 20. If you really need this feature you could fork the GL-native project and try adjusting the [`MAXIMUM_ZOOM`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDK/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/constants/MapboxConstants.java#L58) constant (note that this might result in some rendering issues, use at your own risk).